# CallLog plugin in Ionic framework

Tags: cordova, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I have installed Calllog plugin from GitHub page- https://github.com/dalyc/Cordova-CallLog-Plugin in my mobile application using Visual Studio. While trying to import it in .ts file (typescript file), I am unable to do it as getting an error msg as "{} module '*'".

I am trying to import like:

**import { CallLogService } from 'call-log';**

Can U please help me?

Comment: I believe your ionic/angular app is the latest version of angular which uses typescript. the plugin which you have mentioned is for angular 1.xxx. which won't work as expected

Comment: Can U please suggest a plugin to use in IONIC 2?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this plugin, which will give you access to call log.

https://github.com/atul2889/call-log-call-history-for-Ionic---v2

Comment: Unfortunately, this plugin is not working Anjum, It is not showing any error in simulator while trying to use that plugin and in real device, we are not getting any data related to call logs. We are able to get device specific details(uuid, device manufacturer, OS name etc.). It seems the changes that we make in the Device.Java file is not getting affected. Is there a way to debug that Device.Java file when it is getting executed?, Thanks for your help @Anjum....